# Can Nlog target Azure Log Analytics?

Tags: c#, azure, nlog

I am writing a web api in .NET 6. I don't seem to find a sample where I can write to custom tables under **Azure Log Analytics**. They can be written to via posting a json payload, I was hoping there would be a nuget package library that can already do that taking a workspaceId and sharedkey for access.

Answer (score 1):

*Azure Log Analytics is compatible with the following frameworks .NET Core, .NET 5 and .NET 6.*

*To write custom data collections to Log Analytics using wrapper*

Install-Package LogAnalytics.Client

```cs
LogAnalytics_Wrapper logger = new LogAnalytics_Wrapper(
                workspaceId: "Workspace id,
                sharedKey: "Shared key");
                
await logger.SendLogEntry(new SomeEntity
{
    Category = GetCategory(),
    SomeString = $"String Test",
    SomeBoolean = true,
    SomeDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
    SomeDouble = 2.1,
    SomeGuid = Guid.NewGuid()
}, "testlog")
.ConfigureAwait(false);  ConfigureAwait(false)
```

*Log entries using wrapper*

```cs
LogAnalyticsClient logger = new LogAnalyticsClient(
                workspaceId: "Workspace id",
                sharedKey: "Shared KEY");
List<DemoEntity> entities = new List<DemoEntity>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ii++)
{
    entities.Add(new DemoEntity
    {
        Criticality = GetCriticality(),
        Message = "Message",
        SystemSource = GetSystemSource()
    });
}
await logger.SendLogEntries(entities, "testlog").ConfigureAwait(false)
```

*We can fetch the workspaceId and shared key values from appsettings.json or KeyVault*
[image]

*Fetching the logs from azure using the below command*

```
search *
| where Type == "testlog_CL"
```